# Display some text in vertical order

Tags: html, css

I am using HTML5 and want to display an string in vertical format:
For example: WELCOME can be displayed as:

W

E

L

C

O

M

E

Is it possible to achieve? If yes, how can I do this?
Note: In the example, there are two line break. Please avoid one line break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rotate text using. But for your case this might be better: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DcqmT8D_kzA#t=235

```
.rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);

  /* also accepts left, right, top, bottom coordinates; not required, but a good idea for styling */
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;

  /* Should be unset in IE9+ I think. */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```

EXAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/cbDEK/

Comment: Reviewing your code as per my basic requirements. Accept your answer once it fulfilled my requirements.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [word-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) with some small *width*:

```
p{
    width:10px;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6qHfm/)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to rotate the text, you can also use a big letter-spacing like so:

```
.text{
    letter-spacing: 999em;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```